# c++ no such file or directory - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

so I'm making a program that reads a file which name is specified by the command line argument in Visual studio, now I set the command argument in VS as "data5.txt" and already have that file in the source files folder, However it appears the code still thinks there's no such file or directory

```
std::string filename = argv[1];
std::ifstream in(filename);
if (!in.is_open())
    perror("error");
```

Comment: When you start a application from within VS it might be possible that the root folder is not the one you are expecting. Try running your app from the command line itself. This is just an idea to test. Maybe better responses will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Debugging** settings, the **Working Directory** should be where your data file is in.

[image: VS Settings]

--

@UKMonkey

Or, you can set the **Command Arguments** with the whole path of **"data5.txt"**, eg: **"c:/myvsproject/data5.txt"**

Comment: An alternative is to change "data.txt" to be the full path of the file, eg "c:\myPath\data.txt"

Comment: If your path contain some special char,eg: space. You should use double quote to include the path. eg: "C:\there is a space\my program\data.txt"